# web server failed to start port 7081 was already in use

Tags: java, cmd, jar, executable-jar

identify and stop on port 7081 or configure this application to listen on another port.

how to correct this error.

[image]

Comment: by either stopping the process currently using that port, or by assigning another port to your server

Comment: A server port can only be opened once at a time. There's already an application running that blocks this port. It is very likely that your webserver is still running from a previous run. If you don't know how to shut it down: reboot your machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your program to bind on a different port or kill the existing process running on that port.

```
Run lsof -i :7081 This will display details of process that is listening on port 7081.
copy the process ID 
Run kill -9 <ProcessID> example kill -9 321321
```